# Как разместить варианты ответов викторины в случайном порядке?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Пишу простую викторину на C#: есть 4 кнопки на одной панели, нужно разместить на них варианты ответов. Естественно, правильный не должен постоянно попадать на одну и ту же кнопку.

Как сделать размещение ответов случайным? Какие есть альтернативы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее очевидное решение — отсортировать массив ответов в случайном порядке:

```
// Исходная последовательность ответов
int[] answers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// Объект генератора случайных чисел
Random rnd = new Random();

// Случайная последовательность ответов
answers = answers.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

После этого можно последовательно загрузить каждый из них на соответствующие элементы интерфейса: исходный порядок ответов уже нарушен случайной сортировкой.

**P.S.**
В вашем случае, однако, это должны быть более сложные объекты, хранящие информацию о том, является ли конкретный ответ правильным, или нет.